# AVAudioRecorder never records

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

I am using an `AVAudioRecorder` to record human voice. My code is as follows:

```
// Property of Class
var recorder:AVAudioRecorder?

func recordButtonTapped() {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        if audioSession.recordPermission() != .granted {
            audioSession.requestRecordPermission({ (success) in
                self.startRecording()
            })
        }
        else {
            self.startRecording()
        }

    } catch {
        print("Unable To Set Category")
    }
}

func startRecording() {
    // libraryPathWith(media) just gets the path to the documents directory
    // Like so: Documents/MediaLibrary/Audio/<mediaID>.<mediaExtension>
    if let path = MMFileManager.libraryPathWith(media: self.media) {
        isRecording = true
        do {
            let settings = [
                AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
            ]

            recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: path, settings: settings)

            recorder?.delegate = self

            if recorder!.prepareToRecord() {
                recorder?.record()
            }
        }
        catch {
            isRecording = false
        }
    }
}

func stopRecording() {
    self.recordingLabel.text = "Recording Complete"
    self.recordingLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    if let rec = recorder {
        rec.stop()
        recorder = nil
    }
    isRecording = false
}
```

---

AVAudioRecorderDelegate

```
func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
    print("RECORDED AUDIO SUCCESSFULLY \(flag)")
}
func audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, error: Error?) {
    print("AUDIO RECORDER ERROR \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

---

After I call stop on the AVAudioRecorder the `audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur` function never gets called, but the `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording` function does but the `flag` is always `false`. It prints out `"RECORDED AUDIO SUCCESSFULLY false"`

**QUESTION**

When I record using the code above I does save a file to my documents directory at the location specified. But this file is not something that I can play. It writes a text file, not an audio file as I specify the extension to be `.aac`.

Why does the `AVAudioRecorder` not record audio? And how do I get it to do so?

Comment: The same thing happened to me but it was when I chose another directory like `.downloadsDirectory`. The `flag` parameter was always `false`. So I changed to `.applicationSupportDirectory` or `.downloadsDirectory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the line in the `stopRecording()` function. Below the call to `stop()` the recorder I am immediately assigning the `AVAudioRecorder` instance to `nil`. This deallocates and ends the `AVAudioRecorder` before the post processing to create the authentic `.aac` file can be completed.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, first import

> AVFoundation

and add the AVAudioRecorderDelegate to your ViewController:

```
class RecordViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate
```

then create a global instance of the AVAudioRecorder:

```
var audioRecorder : AVAudioRecorder!
```

Then I created a record button that starts the recording:

```
@IBAction func playButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let recordingName = "voiceRecording.wav"
    let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
    let filePath = URL(string: pathArray.joined(separator: "/"))

    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)

    try! audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: filePath!, settings: [:])
    audioRecorder.delegate = self
    audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    audioRecorder.record()
}
```

**dirPath** finds the directory where the image will be stored.

**recordingName** will set the name of the actual recorded file

**filepath** combines the directory and recordingName for the final location

The rest are pretty much self explanatory.

Then create a pause button which is simpler:

```
@IBAction func pauseButton(_ sender: Any) {

    audioRecorder.stop()
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! audioSession.setActive(false)
}
```

This should solve how you record the audio.

Answer (score 0):

If you've verified your url has the "aac" extension, then I suspect the you simply forgot to call stop() on your recorder.  This results in an un-finalized file.

Also print your errors in the catch block.

```
do{
    try throwingFunc()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have same issue, It occurred because it could not create a file when i call

```
[_audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
```

Fix that by creating an **empty file manually**

```
// Fix strange prepareToRecord Glich 
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            Boolean isFileCreated = [fileManager createFileAtPath:outputFileURL.path contents:NULL attributes:NULL];
```